# Process Template Editor not available for Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, work-item-type

Is there any way to edit the WIT files using the Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise version ?, though there are different extensions available for 2017/2019 etc, but How i can do the same in VS2022 ?

Answer (score 1):

I just found your post from 6 hrs ago looking for the same.

We only have this for 2019 that I can find. This only updates VS2019 unfortunately.  You do have the less than good option to run VS2019 community for accessing the editor, but I'm not sure about licensing.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte

From what I see, Microsoft is instructing to export and modify some existing template, manually editing XML and related files, and then re-uploading the edits as a new template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=visual-studio-2019

I recommend using VS2019 process editor instead.